# Fails to build mpi4py while installing Stanford's Gibson

Tags: python-3.x, linux, mpi, build-error

**System Config:** 
**OS :** Ubuntu 18.04

**Issue:** 
The GibsonEnv fails to install at the step : `pip install -e .` 
Following is the error log (error at the end):

```
(py35) $USER@Cadence:~/GibsonEnv$ pip install -e .
DEPRECATION: Python 3.5 reached the end of its life on September 13th, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 3.5 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 3.5 in January 2021. pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Obtaining file:///home/$USER/GibsonEnv
.
.
.
  /usr/bin/mpicc -pthread -B /home/$USER/anaconda3/envs/py35/compiler_compat _configtest.o -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5 -o _configtest
  /home/$USER/anaconda3/envs/py35/compiler_compat/ld: warning: libopen-rte.so.20, needed by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
  /home/$USER/anaconda3/envs/py35/compiler_compat/ld: warning: libopen-pal.so.20, needed by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
  /home/$USER/anaconda3/envs/py35/compiler_compat/ld: warning: librt.so.1, needed by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
  /home/$USER/anaconda3/envs/py35/compiler_compat/ld: warning: libm.so.6, needed by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
  /home/$USER/anaconda3/envs/py35/compiler_compat/ld: warning: libhwloc.so.5, needed by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_framework_components_close'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_list_sort'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_hwloc_base_get_topology'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_datatype_get_element_count'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_convertor_t_class'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_namelist_t_class'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_var_dump'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_install_dirs'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_hash_table_set_value_ptr'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_rand'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `hwloc_bitmap_alloc'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `hwloc_get_obj_by_depth'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_convertor_raw'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_strncpy'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `hwloc_bitmap_free'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_var_get'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_local_arch'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_list_item_t_class'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_backtrace_print'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_pmix_collect_all_data'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_component_close'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_hash_table_get_value_ptr'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_var_register'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_info_register_framework_params'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `hwloc_bitmap_iszero'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_hwloc_base_cset2mapstr'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_proc_local_set'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `hwloc_bitmap_isincluded'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_datatype_dump_data_flags'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_hwloc_topology'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_convertor_pack'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_output_stream_t_class'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_info_out'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_pmix_base_exchange'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_allocator_base_framework'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_argv_join'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_pmix_base_async_modex'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_datatype_set_element_count'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_pvar_handle_reset'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_argv_free'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_hash_table_init'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_process_info'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_path_nfs'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_pvar_get'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `sync_wait_mt'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_hwloc_base_get_available_cpus'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_backtrace_buffer'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_btl_base_framework'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_pmix_app_t_class'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_progress_set_event_poll_rate'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_pointer_array_test_and_set_item'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_thread_get_self'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_pointer_array_t_class'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_datatype_copy_content_same_ddt'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_components_close'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_pointer_array_init'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `orte_info_show_orte_version'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `orte_init'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_select'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_argv_append_unique_nosize'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_pvar_handle_read_value'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_datatype_finalize'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `orte_session_dir_finalize'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_process_name_print'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_pvar_handle_alloc'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `hwloc_get_type_depth'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `clock_gettime@GLIBC_2.2.5'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_buffer_t_class'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_convert_process_name_to_string'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_free_list_t_class'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_abort_delay'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_output'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `sqrt@GLIBC_2.2.5'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_var_find_by_name'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_progress'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_hwloc_base_single_cpu'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_compare_proc'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_free_list_item_t_class'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_datatype_contain_basic_datatypes'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_framework_is_open'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_convertor_prepare_for_recv'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `hwloc_bitmap_compare'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_hash_table_t_class'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_dss'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_value_unload'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_built_with_cuda_support'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_var_set_value'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_progress_register'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_info_register_project_frameworks'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_hash_table_get_next_key_uint32'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_pointer_array_add'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `orte_util_compare_name_fields'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_finalize_util'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_output_close'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_progress_event_users_increment'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_pointer_array_set_item'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `orte_in_parallel_debugger'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_convertor_prepare_for_send'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_hash_table_remove_value_uint32'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `orte_rml_recv_callback'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_mpool_base_framework'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `orte_ess'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_value_load'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_var_enum_create_flag'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_bitmap_set_bit'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_info_close_components'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_output_verbose'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `orte_process_info'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_argv_append_nosize'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `hwloc_get_cpubind'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_pmix_pdata_t_class'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_pvar_handle_free'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `orte_info_close_components'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `orte_proc_applied_binding'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_component_var_register'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `orte_proc_is_bound'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `orte_name_wildcard'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_var_get_value'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_rcache_base_framework'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_var_find'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_pvar_handle_write_value'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_hwloc_base_cset2str'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_mpool_base_alloc'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_init_util'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `orte_rml'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_convertor_create'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_output_open'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_thread_self_compare'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_free_list_grow_st'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_condition_t_class'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_show_help'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_datatype_predefined_elem_desc'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_cuda_support'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_datatype_clone'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `orte_odls'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_mpool_base_free'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_progress_set_event_flag'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `clock_getres@GLIBC_2.2.5'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_convertor_unpack'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_var_register_synonym'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_hash_table_get_value_uint32'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_var_group_find_by_name'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_argv_split'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_strerror'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_var_group_get_stamp'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_pvar_session_t_class'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_pmix'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_srand'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_arch_set_fortran_logical_size'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_object_t_class'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `orte_util_convert_process_name_to_string'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_pvar_get_count'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_mpool_base_tree_print'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_class_initialize'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_progress_set_yield_when_idle'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_bitmap_is_set_bit'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_var_get_count'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_pvar_find_by_name'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_proc_for_name'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_framework_close'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_bitmap_init'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_framework_components_open'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_datatype_t_class'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `orte_standalone_operation'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_uses_threads'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `orte_util_convert_string_to_process_name'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_proc_t_class'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_argv_append'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_mutex_t_class'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_component_to_string'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `orte_util_print_name_args'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_allocator_component_lookup'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_pvar_handle_stop'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_datatype_init'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_hash_table_set_value_uint32'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_abort_print_stack'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `log@GLIBC_2.2.5'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_hash_table_get_value_uint64'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_var_group_get'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_convert_string_to_process_name'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_datatype_commit'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_bitmap_find_and_set_first_unset_bit'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_getcwd'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `orte_errmgr'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_datatype_dump_data_desc'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_var_enum_create'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_component_repository_release'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_value_t_class'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_free_list_init'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_bitmap_set_max_size'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_info_make_version_str'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_progress_unregister'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_pvar_handle_start'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_datatype_create_desc'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_setenv'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_progress_event_users_decrement'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_hash_table_remove_value_ptr'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `orte_finalize'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_bitmap_clear_bit'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_bitmap_t_class'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_hash_table_get_first_key_uint32'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_component_list_item_t_class'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `orte_info_register_framework_params'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_framework_open'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `orte_rml_recv_cb_t_class'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `orte_session_dir_cleanup'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_info_show_opal_version'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_datatype_add'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `mca_base_var_group_get_count'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_datatype_resize'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_hash_table_set_value_uint64'
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `opal_list_t_class'
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  failure.
  removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
  error: Cannot link MPI programs. Check your configuration!!!
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mpi4py
Failed to build mpi4py
ERROR: Could not build wheels for mpi4py which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Please let me know if any more information is required from my side. 
Any help is appreciated, TIA!!

Comment: that could be a busted Open MPI installation. what if you `ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib | grep libopen`? are you sure `/usr/bin/mpicc` is the wrapper for Open MPI ?

Comment: The output of  `ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib | grep libopen` is as follows :
`$USER@Cadence:~$ ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib | grep libopen
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     22 Feb  5  2018 libopen-pal.so -> libopen-pal.so.20.10.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 701656 Feb  5  2018 libopen-pal.so.20.10.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     22 Feb  5  2018 libopen-rte.so -> libopen-rte.so.20.10.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 550192 Feb  5  2018 libopen-rte.so.20.10.1`

What do you mean by a 'busted' Open MPI installation?

Comment: the `libopen-pal.so.20` symlink should be in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. Can you confirm it is there (and pointing to a valid file) ? if so, it seems `pip` is not looking in this directory, and this is odd. That could be an `anaconda` issue, so you might want to first install Open MPI in your anaconda environment, and make sure `pip` uses `mpicc` from the anaconda environment.